# Wordpress Customize the_content

Tags: wordpress

I am quite new to Wordpress and try to customize my Wordpress theme. My posts are always different. But basically there is a title, a text and a NivoSlider/Image/Vimeo Video.

If I use the basic **the_content** function it displays the post like that:

```
<h2>Title of the Post</h2>
<p><div class="slider-wrapper">Slider</div>Text</p>
```

It always includes the Slider/Image/Video in the

Tag. How can I split **the_content** object?

I would like to have my posts display like that e.g. for the NivoSlider:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">Slider</div> 
<h2>Title of the Post</h2>
<p><Text</p>
```

It would be really great if somebody could tell me the easiest way to do for all the different kinds of posts.

I hope you understand my explanation, if you need more details, just tell me.

Thanks in advanced.

Best,
Brigi

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would take the shortcode out from your Content Body altogether, and place it in a Custom Field (named something like "postSlider"). Then you can structure your template like so:

```
<?php
do_shortcode(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'postSlider'));
?>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
```

Comment: Thank you! I installed the Custom Field Template Plugin. It works really fine, but I don't know how to get the input of my custom field to my website, respectively what shortcode I can use in my index.php file. Do you know how to use that plugin?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't used that one before. The problem with using plugins to define custom fields is that you can name them one thing, but the plugin might prepend or append a string to the slug and name it something else. My example uses Wordpress' built-in Custom Fields which you can view/add/update/delete by enabling them in your Post Editor (Click Screen Options in the upper right-hand corner). After that, you'll have to find out which theme file to update.

Answer (score 0):

You needs to [**create a custom page template**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) for your posts. In that page template you can define your slider. Then just put your text in the content section.

Before doing serious coding refer this: [Stepping Into Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for your answer. Finally I used the Types plugin for Wordpress. You can easily customize your own field and use it in your index.php file with the following code:

**Custom Field Image:**

```
<?php echo(types_render_field("field-slug-image", array("alt"=>"Product image", "width"=>"600","height"=>"300","proportional"=>"true"))); ?>
```

**Shortcode Custom Field for the Slider:**

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'field-slug-slider', true)); ?>
```

**Shortcode Custom Field for the Vimeo video:**

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'field-slug-video', true)); ?>
```

**Title and Content:**

```
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_content('Read the full post',true);?>
```